# program for an integer adjacency list using linked list

Tags: java, adjacency-list

```
public class AdjList {
    private Node first;        // beginning of list
    private int N;             // size of lis
private static class Node {
       int a;
        Node next;
        Node(int a, Node next) {
            this.a = a;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() { return (first == null); }
    public int size()        { return N; }

    public void insert(int a) {
        first = new Node(a, first);
        N++;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AdjList adjlist = new AdjList();
        adjlist.insert(1);
        adjlist.insert(2);
        adjlist.insert(3);
        adjlist.insert(4);

        System.out.println(adjlist);
    }
}
```

i am trying to write a code on adjacency list using linked list.data items are integers,but it shows error 
this is the code i have tried .but it return some other values.can u help me

AdjList@6e1408 is the output

Comment: "Shows error?" What error? Are you sure it's not just showing the reference to your `AdjList` object, since you didn't override `toString`?

Comment: AdjList@6e1408 is the output.i'm a beginner .how to override .can u rewrite the code

Comment: You must add a method to `AdjList` with the signature `public String toString()` that returns a string containing the formatted output you want to see when you print an object of type `AdjList`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two `toString()` methods, perhaps something like this for the `AdjList`

```
public String toString() {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.append("AdjList [").append(N).append("] = {");
  Node n = this.first;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    if (i != 0) {
      sb.append(", ");
    }
    sb.append(n.toString());
    n = n.next;
  }
  sb.append("}");
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Then for your `Node` you need another one, perhaps something like this

```
public String toString() {
  return String.valueOf(a);
}
```

I think you will get something more like what you expected if you try those.